# Move RSS feed in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have 1 main account called A and 1 secondary account called B.
A has a special RSS feed folder and B is the new main account (also in outloo settings) and I want to move the special RSS folder in B.

How I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Time did the thing. I suppose that if close and open Outlook everything will be fixed.